# Finding the largest even digit in a given integer

Tags: c, arrays

I am taking an online C class, but the professor refuses to answer emails and I needed some help.

Anyways, our assignment was to write a program that takes an integer from the user and find the largest even digit and how many times the digit occurs in the given integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void extract(int);
void menu(void);


int main() {
    menu();
}

void menu() {
    int userOption;
    int myValue;
    int extractDigit;

    do {
        printf("\nMENU"
            "\n1. Test the function"
            "\n2. Quit");
        scanf("%d", &userOption);

        switch (userOption) {
        case 1:
            printf("Please enter an int: ");
            scanf("%d", &myValue);

            extractDigit = digitExtract(myValue);

            break;

        case 2:
            printf("\nExiting . . . ");
            break;

        default:
            printf("\nPlease enter a valid option!");
        }
    } while (userOption != 2);
}

void digitExtract(int userValue) {
    int tempValue;
    int x;
    int myArr[10] = { 0 };

    tempValue = (userValue < 0) ? -userValue : userValue;

    do {
        myArr[tempValue % 10]++;
        tempValue /= 10;
    } while (tempValue != 0);


    printf("\nFor %d:\n", userValue);
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        printf("\n%d occurence(s) of %d",myArr[x], x);
    }   
}
```

I have gotten the program to display both odd & even digit and it's occurrences.

The only part that I am stuck on is having the program to display ONLY the largest even digit and it's occurrence. Everything I've tried has either broken the program's logic or produces some weird output.

Any hints or ideas on how I should proceed?

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Just check the even digits in descending order (8, 6, 4) and print and break if `myArr[x] > 0`

Comment: you can use an array of 10 to store the count,when the user exits you find the max count and then print the index

Comment: Minor: Note: code has problems if `myValue == INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a loop from the largest even digit to smallest even digit.

```
for (x = 8; x >=0; x-=2)
{
    if(myArr[x]>0) //if myArr[x]=0 then x does not exist
    {
        printf("%d occurs %d times",x,myArr[x]);
        break; //we have found our maximum even digit. No need to proceed further
    }

}
```

Note:To optimize you should count and store occurrences of only even digits.

Comment: Thanks, would it be the most efficient to implement an if statement to check for the largest even digit?

Comment: No.The idea is to start checking from the largest possible even digit,which is `8`.If `8` occurs, it's count is our answer and we break.If `8` does not occur we check for the next largest even digit which is `6` and so on.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I understand the use of break now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even use the extra loop? To find the largest even digit in an integer and the number of its occurences, a modification to the first loop would suffice.

Consider the following (untested, but I hope you get the idea):

```
int tempValue;
int x;
int myArr[10] = { 0 };

int maxNum = 0;

tempValue = (userValue < 0) ? -userValue : userValue;

do {
    int currNum = tempValue % 10;

    myArr[currNum]++;
    tempValue /= 10;

    if (currNum % 2 == 0 && currNum > maxNum)
        maxNum = currNum;
} while (tempValue != 0);
```

After this, `maxNum` should contain the largest even digit, and `myArr[maxNum]` should be the number of its occurences.